# Relaying a contract call from contract A to contract C via contract B

Tags: solidity

Let's say contract **A** does not know the address of contract **C** but it knows what function of **C** it wants to call. Contract **B** stores contracts's **C** address. Therefore contract **A** wants to request a call to **C**'s function but at the address of contract **B**.
Furthermore, the function returns a value about which contract **A** cares. Essentially, contract **C** is a library that contract **A** wants to use for his own computations but does not know the libraries' address.

Now, I have looked into various ways of doing this with **call**, **delegatecall** and **fallback** function but I think it might not be possible to do it exactly like that.

For example, there was once suggested solution [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/186/how-can-i-update-contracts-after-they-are-created/190#190) which I hope is fine to copy here for convenience:

```
contract Relay {
address public currentVersion;
address public owner;

function Relay(address initAddr){
    currentVersion = initAddr;
    owner = msg.sender;
}

function(){
    if(!currentVersion.delegatecall(msg.data)) throw;
}
```

Solution 1:
I have tried something like the above code, making my contract **B** to have a fallback function. However, when **A** executed a **call** to **C** through it then it returned me some strange result back to **A** which made me believe that it will just not work this way for some reason; the result of **C** will not return through fallback back to **A**.

Solution 2:
The closest I got it to work is when I had **A** execute a **delegatecall** to **B** which in turn executes the **delegatecall** to **C**. This meant that **C** was executing in the context of **A** and so when I set a storage variable in **C**, I am actually setting a storage variable in **A**. Then I had the result of the computation stored in a state variable in **A** which is not bad. However, this solution also means that **B** needs to have hardcoded all the variables/logic in the fallback function and cannot access its storage variables because it executes in the context of **A**. It cannot have the address of **C** stored in a state variable like the currentVersion in the example above.

I am not sure if everything what I wrote is correct but this is my take on it. I am hoping that maybe solution 1 should still be possible but I did something wrong? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6):

Instead of relaying the call, why not just use contract **B** to store the value and have contract **A** read the value? Instead of delegating the call to **B**, read the address from **B** and delegate directly to **C**.

Comment: I was playing around with the idea of hiding the address of C to A altogether (by obfuscation, at least) plus having the fallback function of B to charge A to do this relay.

Comment: You can't really hide it, that's beyond current technology. You can still charge, though. In order to fetch the address, **A** would have to call a function of **B** that requires payment

Comment: Does it mean that the above Relay contract example is not really going to work for calls with return values?

Comment: Hey @md2312 I'm trying to accomplish exactly the same as you (hide a contract behind a relay/dispatcher contract so I can update it later if necessary), but I'm stuck with functions with return values and the `delegatecall` approach. Does all of this ended up working for you?

Comment: It can be tricky if you want to be able to return values, but it  can definitely be done with a little inline assembly

Comment: Would you have an example, @TjadenHess ?